# How to use angular 2 scope variables and functions in jquery and vice versa

Tags: angular

Following is a sample code of angular4 component.
I want those scope variable and function to be accessed in jquery onclick method

@import ...

```
declare let jQuery: any;

@Component ({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...'
})

export class ComponentName {
   variable1: any;

   jQuery("#btn").on("click", function(){
      // here I want to access 'variable1' and call 'displaySomething()'
   });

   displaySomething(): void {
       // statements
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this way :

```
jQuery("#btn").on("click", () => { // use fat arrow function inplace of function()
    console.log(this.variable1);
    this.displaySomething();
    // here I want to access 'variable1' and call 'displaySomething()'
});
```

---

> Note : Don't use jQuery so much , try to do everything in angular's
>   way like :

```
// Template Side
<button id="btn" (click)='yourFunction()'>Click Me</button>

// Component Side
displaySomething(){
    console.log(this.variable1);
    this.displaySomething();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. Actually It was the part of UI template that's why used as it is with JQuery.